# How To Know Whether a mouse moved left or right

Tags: mousemove, purescript

I am new to Purescript and currently working with Mouse Events. I would like to know how to identify when the mouse moved left and when the mouse moved right and what Events it would generate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell from an individual mouse event, it just raises a `mousemove` `MouseEvent` in both cases. To determine the direction the cursor is travelling you'd check the difference between `pageX` properties of the event over time.